# Reset closest select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I need to reset the closest select dropdown when clicking a button. Not sure which is not working here, wrong selector or wrong reset method?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/CeSrE/

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('select').val('');
});
```

```
<div class="controls">
    <button class="btn btn-link remove" type="button">Reset</button>

    <select id="oberservationType" class=" pull-left">
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>Mauris elementum</option>
        <option>Eros id dapibus</option>
        <option>Vestibulum erat</option>
        <option>Ultricies lacus magna</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest() is for parents, use `.next()` or `.nextAll()` if not directly next targetted element instead:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CeSrE/2/)

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
    $(this).next('select').val('');
});​
```